# android ndk: are -fPIC and -pie mututally exclusive?

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk, ocaml

I'm building Unison (a file synchronization executable) for Android using the Android r10e NDK, but this isn't really an Android question.

Android > 5.0 (SDK 21) requires executables to be position-independent.  So I
pass -pie to arm-linux-androideabi-gcc while compiling, which works:

```
% hardening-check ./unison
./unison:
Position Independent Executable: yes
...
```

This works fine on Android 5.0 devices.

Android > 6.0 (SDK 21) still requires executables to be position-independent,
but **also** requires executables to be built without text relocations.  So I
pass -fPIC to arm-linux-androideabi-gcc while compiling, and it appears to build
a binary without text relocations:

```
% arm-linux-androideabi-readelf -a ./unison |& grep TEXTREL
(no output is shown)
```

The problem is, I can only satisfy one requirement at a time.  If I use -pie and
-fPIC together, the resulting executable is position-independent (yay!), but
also has text relocations (boo!):

```
% hardening-check ./unison
./unison:
Position Independent Executable: yes
...

% arm-linux-androideabi-readelf -a ./unison |& grep TEXTREL
0x00000016 (TEXTREL)                    0x0
0x0000001e (FLAGS)                      TEXTREL BIND_NOW
```

...and Android 6.0 devices refuse to run it:

```
% adb push unison /data/local/tmp 
% adb shell '/data/local/tmp/unison -version'
WARNING: linker: /data/local/tmp/unison has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: can't protect segments for "/data/local/tmp/unison": Permission denied
```

What's the special sauce needed to get these flags to work together?  Or,
alternatively, what am I missing?  Are PIC and PIE mutually exclusive?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I am manually walking through the same process that the OPAM repo goes through to build Unison for Android.  Namely:

1. Build the ocaml cross compilers.
2. Pull down the Unison source.
3. Apply a patch:

   ```
   --- pty.c~  2010-04-15 19:29:31.000000000 +0200
   +++ pty.c   2013-01-16 19:28:56.258812188 +0100
   @@ -10,7 +10,7 @@
   extern void uerror (char * cmdname, value arg) Noreturn;

   // openpty
   -#if defined(__linux)
   +#if defined(__linux) && !defined(__ANDROID__)
   #include <pty.h>
   #define HAS_OPENPTY 1
   #endif
   --- Makefile.OCaml~ 2013-01-16 19:27:10.686807807 +0100
   +++ Makefile.OCaml  2013-01-16 19:29:46.814814286 +0100
   @@ -136,7 +136,9 @@
       # openpty is in the libutil library
       ifneq ($(OSARCH),solaris)
       ifneq ($(OSARCH),osx)
   -        CLIBS+=-cclib -lutil
   +        ifneq ($(OSCOMP),android)
   +          CLIBS+=-cclib -lutil
   +        endif
       endif
       endif
       buildexecutable::
   ```
4. Build with:

   ```
   % make \
       UISTYLE=text \
       OCAMLOPT="arm-linux-androideabi-ocamlopt -verbose -ccopt '-fPIC -pie'" \
       OSCOMP=android
   ```

The above process builds a PIE executable that runs fine on Android 5, but fails on Android 6 because it has text relocations.  Removing "-pie" above build a binary without text relocations, but is not a PIE executable so it won't run on Android 5 or 6.

Comment: Can you provide the details on how you configure and do your build, to help others reproduce? (Building a trivial test app probably won't produce the same text relocations.)

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add that for some people seeing this question, thinking it matches their problem perfectly,

[text relocations despite -fPIC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957435/text-relocations-despite-fpic)

will be the correct answer.  In short, after double checking all your "C" code settings, don't forget assembly code problems.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with something similar after the release of Lollipop. Since that moment, the use of PIE executable has been mandatory in order to ensure a better ASLR.

**Provided that you can live with only 4.1+** support, a simple solution is just set `APP_PLATFORM := android-16`.
By doing that,the compiler will activate the -fPIE flag at some stage.

This could be a very straightforward example of how your Application.mk migh look.

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
APP_PLATFORM := android-16
APP_OPTIM : = release
APP_ABI := armeabi
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Comment: Thanks David, but this doesn't quite address my question.  The -fPIE flag is already being passed successfully to the build process.  The problem is that the resulting binary does not run on Android > 6.0 (Marshmallow) because it was not compiled with -fPIC.  Adding -fPIC to the build process results in a non-PIE executable that won't run on Android > 5.0 (Lollipop).

Comment: For that reason, IMHO, the most easy and safe way if you can live without 4.1+ support is just let the compiler address these flags by itself.

Answer (score 0):

The flags you're using should be right, although I haven't tried using the ocaml (cross) compiler. On a large, pure C codebase, I manage to build PIE executables without text relocations, by passing `-fPIC` during compilation and `-fPIE -pie` during linking.

The way you describe that the flags override each other sounds weird. My guess is that it somehow comes from how the ocaml frontend pass them on to the backend tools via the `-ccopt` parameter. The `-pie` flag is a linker flag, so it shouldn't need to be passed to the compilation steps at all. And if it isn't passed to the compilation steps, the generated code should be identical to before, it's only the linking step that should change, right?

Can you check which object files actually contain text relocations, and what compiler options they are built with? (I'm not sure if this is visible anywhere, I assume it's called internally by `ocamlopt`.) If none of the individual object files contain text relocations, it seems like they would come from some of the ocaml specific object files that get linked in?

Comment: I had the same thought, but I'm not sure how to check an individual object file for text relocations.  Can you enlighten me?  Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I noticed after posting this that it isn't quite as easy to check for it as I suspected, so currently I don't really have any good idea for doing that.

Comment: Are you able to build without `-pie` and just rerun the linker command manually with that added?

Comment: Just tried that with the same result.  It's not clear to me whether objects have relocations that make their way into the resulting executable, or whether relocations are purely the product of linking.  If the former, then finding a way to test an object for relocations would be very helpful in identifying the offending object(s).