# Can't run iperf3 on android without root permission

Tags: java, android, networking

I need to make android application that run iperf3 library, so i have compiled "iperf3" using android-ndk-r20 with changes made in

iperf_api.c

`char buf[] = "/tmp/iperf3.XXXXXX";` I've replaced with `char buf[] = "/data/local/tmp/iperf3.XXXXXX";`, figured it out how to package it with my android application and run. But I don't know how to run it without "su" (root) permissions.

Well working code:

```
ArrayList<String> commandLine = new ArrayList<String>();
commandLine.add("su");
commandLine.add("-c");
commandLine.add(getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir+"/libiperf3.so -c speedtest.hostkey.ru -t 10 -i 5 -P 3 -d");
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine.toArray(new String[0]));
```

It works well with "su", but I need to made it work without root. When I try same code but with "su" replaced by "sh" I get this error:

```
iperf3: error - unable to create a new stream: Permission denied
```

I don't know how to made it work, there is some applications that are using iperf3 in Google Play Store without root permissions, so it is possible. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out how to make it work. Before compile "iperf3" you need to change followed line in "iperf_api.c"

```
char buf[] = "/tmp/iperf3.XXXXXX";
```

to `char buf[] = "/data/data/your.package.name/cache/iperf3.XXXXXX";`
And it works fine!
I hope I helped someone.

Answer (score 1):

It is also working when you set any of the following environment variable to writable directory (ie. cacheDir): `TMPDIR` or `TEMP` or `TMP`

For example:
`Os.setenv("TEMP", CACHE_DIR, true)`

Temporary directory is checked in `iperf_api.c` `iperf_new_stream` function.